# Remove duplicate data from cursor and get data when value increase

Tags: java, android

```
1 | AB    | BCD   | ref  | Ferari|
----------------------------------
1 | AB    | BCD   | ref  | TOYOTA|
----------------------------------
1 | AB    | BCD   | ref| AUDI |
----------------------------------
1 | AB    | BCD    | ref| BMW  |
---------------------------------
2 | BC    | ABC   | ref  | NISSAN|
----------------------------------
2 | BC    | ABC   | ref  | SUZKI|
----------------------------------
2 | BC    | ABC   | ref| TATA |
```

Cursor hold data like this table. Now, I want get data like

```
getTopic = AB
getTitle= BCD
getType = ref
Names   = FERARI TOYOTA AUDI BMW
```

I tried with this

```
   do{
       int current = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
       String Title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TITLE"));
       if(!StoreTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(Title) && lastId != current){

           getTopic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TOPIC"));
           getTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TITLE"));
           getType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TYPE"));
           getName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME"));

       }else{
              getName = getName +" "+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME"));
           }

       lastId = current;
       StoreTitle = Title;
 }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

But, it's not showing expected result. It's showing `BC` column with `Names` FERARI TOYOTA AUDI BMW.

As I am also checking `lastitem!= currentitem` for this it's also not showing the last author name.

Now, my question is

1) What should I do to get the expected result ? 
2) As I am also checking `lastitem!= currentitem` for this it's also not showing the last author name. But, How can I store that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work *(untested)*:

```
SparseArray<Data> dataArray = new SparseArray<Data>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE"));
        String topic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TOPIC"));
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TYPE"));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
        Data d = dataArray.get(id);
        if (d == null) {
            d = new Data(id, title, topic, type);
            d.names.add(name);
            dataArray.put(id, d);
        } else {
            d.names.add(name);
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());


// now you can get names like this
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.size(); i++) {
        Data d = dataArray.get(i);
        String names = TextUtils.join(" ", d.names); 
    }
```

Where `Data` is:

```
private class Data {
    int id;
    String title, topic, type;
    List<String> names;

    public Data(int id, String title, String topic, String type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.type = type;
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I get the names ?